# Why are "the first" vampires immune to all of the normal vampire weaknesses?

Tags: vampire, vampire-chronicles, blade

In the *Blade* movie series and the *Vampire Chronicles* movies (and possibly others) they depict the "first" (original) vampires as being like gods. They have all the strengths of the vampires (often to a much greater power) and none of the weaknesses. They are much like the Balkan creatures dhampir, but they aren't a human/vampire hybrid.

Why is it that these first creatures have no weaknesses, but their children and victims (those they turn to vampires) do?

**Edit**: The weaknesses I refer to are silver, sunlight and garlic.

Comment: I may shoot myself for admitting that I know this, but the Vampire Diaries has the same issue, with (AFAIK) absolutely no explanation given other than "they're the original vampires."

Comment: @KutuluMike In Vampire Diaries, it's explained that the original vampires get these perks because they were turned by an immortality spell, not by another vampire. Or something like that anyway lol

Comment: As far as Warhammer fantasy goes, the older you are, the stronger you are...

Comment: The *Blade* movie series may be the same - the longer you've been a vampire, the stronger you become. Also, this may be less a matter of *no* weaknesses, but of reduced vulnerability - I've seen that in some vampire stories.

Answer (score 7):

In the Vampire Chronicles, Anne Rice explains (in *The Queen of the Damned* maybe?) that Akasha and the first vampires are incredibly strong because of their age.  The longer they are "alive" the stronger they become until they are virtually indestructible.  Marius says that at one point one of their guardians was so desperate to be rid of them that while they were sleeping he put Akasha and Enkil out into the burning sunlight to destroy them, but awoke in the morning only to find himself badly burned and Those Who Must Be Kept merely sunburnt.  Apparently, whatever happens to them happens to all vampires (their descendants since they are the first).

ETA:  Akasha and Enkil were originally humans and rulers of a kingdom called Kemet.  When some unhappy subjects attempt to assassinate the king and queen, Akasha becomes inhabited by a demon called Amel as her soul is leaving her body.  Her soul, now combined with Amel, reenters her body through her wounds and she awakens a vampire.  She immediately turns Enkil into a vampire, and they become Those Who Must Be Kept.

Apparently, younger vampires can gain strength by drinking from older vampires.  Lestat drinks from Akasha numerous times throughout *Queen of the Damned* and gains enough strength to be able to fly, survive sunlight, and a few other things I think.

ETA (again):  I don't think Anne Rice mentions any specific weakness of vamps except sunlight, which, as we've stated, can be overcome if a vamp hangs around long enough and grows strong enough.  This might be something she's changed as I've only read up through *Memnoch the Devil*.

I don't know about *Blade*.

Comment: So, in the Vamp Chronicles, if a vamp were to live long enough, they would become god-like, like Akasha? Did she give a timeline as to how long it would take to gain these feats?

Comment: I think it mentions in the book that she is made a vamp c. 5000 BC.  I'm not certain at what "age" she became virtually indestructible, but we know that vampires like Marius and Pandora who are well over 2000 years old are very, very strong and difficult to kill.  Interestingly enough, they aren't completely indestructible.  Akasha kills Enkil when she awakens by drinking all his blood and he shatters like glass, and Akasha is herself killed by decapitation and having her brain and heart eaten by another vampire.

Comment: In Barbara Hambly's Vampire books, age also increases the resistance of vampires to sun and other weaknesses and increases the power.  An aged vampire that had been alive for about a 1000 years kills an artifical vampire by daywalking, injecting his blood with silver nitrate and allowing the monster to drink his blood.

Answer (score 6):

The most usual explanation in most vampire folklore has to do with the purity of the blood. As more generations go by, the original blood of a vampire get mixed with and diluted in human blood and thus younger vampires tend to be less powerful than older vampires who has a more pure, uncontaminated blood.

Since vampiric blood is the source of most vampire powers (as usually conversion involves drinking a given amount of the vampire blood) that explains why the "elders" are almost always consistently the most powerful vampires.

Answer (score 5):

In the first Blade movie there were Vampire Elders but they had the standard vampire weaknesses.
In Blade II vampire elder Eli Damaskinos attempts to make vampires immune to sunlight, garlic,  and silver.  Instead he creates the Reapers.  While they were immune to silver and garlic and had a bone shield around their heart they were not immune to sunlight.

In Blade: Trinity the vampires sought out Dracula.  This was not the Bram Stoker version of the character however.  This Dracula or "Drake" is the progenitor of *Hominus Nocturna.*  From him descended all the vampires.  He is not a human turned into a vampire but a different creature entirely.  His origin is unknown but he is old.  Old old.  Worshiped as Dagon by the ancient Babylonians old.
Drake is immune to sunlight and silver but is killed with an arrow designed to inject the Daystar virus which when mixed with Drake's blood will wipe out all vampires on earth.

In the Blade movie series, barring a reboot, there are no more vampires.

Comment: I thought that virus was only strong enough to kill all the vamps in New York, not the world. The blind chick (I forget the character's name) mentions this in her video will.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris I'll have to watch it again and see.  I was fairly certain it created an airborne virus that would wipe out vampires world wide.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to 'possibly others', Underworld presents 'firsts' who aren't godlike. I think it's the second movie? The progenitor and his two sons - who create the vampire/werewolf bloodlines - are all killed off. Outside of a nasty helicopter rotor accident, the methods used to kill them are pretty mundane.

Answer (score 0):

In the Vampire Chronicles, their strength derives from Amel, the spirit that animates them. A portion of its energy goes not just to animation, but to converting their bodies into the perfect vehicle for immortality. This is why they cannot stand sunlight...Amel cant stand the light of day while having to constantly expend energy (think exercising outside at noon) because the blood is flammable.  As they age and Amel gets closer to completing his work the sun affects them less and they become more powerful because less of Amel's energy goes towards their "metabolism." This means that of course sun affects them less, they heal faster, gain in strength both physically and mentally, etc.

Comment: This seems right, but could you add a reference to this?

Comment: QotD, but this is commented on many time throughout the series by all of the older ones. Maharet explains their origin for all of the fledglings while they are at her compound in QotD, Marius explains this to Lestat in TVL, Khayman dwells on the differences between him and 3 fledglings he encounters in QotD. Even in The Tale of the Body Thief, Louis comments that because of the amount of Akasha's blood that he's drunk, the Children of the Millennia (Mael, Marius, Pandora) don't have the combined strength to destroy him

Answer (score -1):

this may be unrelated but in blade the 1st one with Frost, they stated in the movie that he was weaker because he was not born vampire but did not elaborate, could vampires have children other than with human females? ( that scene when he was talking to the elders and they sneered at him, because he was vampire through metamorphosis [bitten])

the first could have been born "undead" (by a curse ou demon or virus in utero?) and thus the strongest? 
the bitten would go throught metamorphosis and lose some of the mutated virus thus being weaker, and over centuries losing the daywaking abilities and becoming fataly alergic to garlic?

Comment: Your answer has a lot of question marks for a answer. I think that you should fix that, because if you aren't sure of yourself then nobody will be. Also, if you keep the question marks add some links or something to give your answer credibility. I would have up-voted if there was less question marks, because your reasoning wasn't that bad.

Answer (score -4):

The reason is because the original vampires have the original spell of being eternally protected against being killed. The spell, like all "black" or "evil" magic has consequences on the caster and the person/people they cast I on like all spells that have unnatural effects where in this case being immune to being killed. The consiquenses was eternal life and the need to drink blood to sustain their own body from decay. The spell can be passed down from person to person but the farther away from the original vampires the weaker the magic becomes. Like when spreading butter on bread, if you start in the middle it will have the most but as you spread to one side it will become thinner and thinner. Werewolves were made through vengeance of the murderous vampires.

Originally the spell was meant to only turn the humans into these wolf like beasts for one night, the full moon, to kill all the vampires. Which is also why a werewolf bite is deadly to a vampire. The unforseen consequences of something this unnatural is they lose control of themselves every full moon and kill everything in their path.

Since a werewolf bite is deadly to a vampire the only guaranteed way to become a hybrid is to become a werewolf first then let another vampire or hybrid turn you into a vampire and drink a hybrids blood.

Comment: What canon is this from?

Comment: Now I'm just confused and hungry for a buttered roll.