# Were all vampires in the entire world killed at the end of Blade 3 movie?

Tags: vampire, blade

Based on discussion in comments on [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12060/976), I wondered:

**Did shooting Drake with the DayStar virus result in killing only nearby (same city) vampires, or ALL vampires worldwide?**

Canon evidence only please, and no 4th-wall "of course not - they need a sequel" answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

David Goyer wrote all three Blade movies and later co-created [the TV series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade%3a_The_Series) which takes place after Blade: Trinity.

From the Wikipedia page:

> The TV series takes place after Blade: Trinity since certain events in that film were mentioned in the pilot episode. At the end of Trinity, Blade used the Daystar, a biological weapon that targets and kills vampires specifically. However, the Daystar has not spread as far or as fast as originally designed, as there are still many vampire houses in operation (for example, Marcus, in the second episode, mentions twelve existing vampire Houses to Krista).

Comment: Blade survived the virus. So maybe there are other vamp mutations around that would have been immune to the virus as well.

Comment: The TV series basically retconned the events of the movies so that Blade took down the House of Erebus, which was the largest and most powerful house, rather than the entire Vampire Nation.

Answer (score 2):

No as was said in the movie, only in the vicinity of the city.

Also since Daystar didn't kill Blade because he is a hybrid, the same thing should be true for Drake as he was THE hybrid: the first known king.